# Delete multiple strings/characters in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a curl output generated similar below, Im working on a SED/AWK script to eliminate unwanted strings.

File

```
{id":"54bef907-d17e-4633-88be-49fa738b092d","name":"AA","description","name":"AAxxxxxx","enabled":true}
{id":"20000000000000000000000000000000","name":"BB","description","name":"BBxxxxxx","enabled":true}
{id":"542ndf07-d19e-2233-87gf-49fa738b092d","name":"AA","description","name":"CCxxxxxx","enabled":true}
{id":"20000000000000000000000000000000","name":"BB","description","name":"DDxxxxxx","enabled":true}

......
```

I like to modify this file and retain similar below,

```
AA AAxxxxxx
BB BBxxxxxx
AA CCxxxxxx
BB DDxxxxxx
AA n.....
BB n.....
```

Is there a way I could remove word/commas/semicolons in-between so I can only retain these values?

Comment: `sed -r 's/.*name":"([^"]+).*name":"([^"]+).*/\1 \2/' file`

Comment: The response looks quite like JSON, although it is currently malformed. Have you accidentally broken the format when copying a sample into your question?

Comment: its actually a report file its quite long, and cropped some values to shorten the sample, I'm just looking for a way to just get those Values after "name" and print it, all other words/characters thereafter become irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `awk`

```
curl your_command | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-9),$(NF-3)}'
```

Or:

```
curl your_command | awk -F\" '{print $7,$13}'
```

A semantic approach ussing `perl`:

```
curl your_command | perl -lane '/"name":"(\w+)".*"name":"(\w+)"/;print $1." ".$2'
```

For any number of `name` ocurrences:

```
curl your_command | perl -lane 'printf $_." " for ( $_ =~ /"name":"(\w+)"/g);print ""'
```

Comment: Why not use the `-F` flag ? Also why if you are picking specific fields are you using `NF-` . Could be `awk -F\" '{print $7,$13}'`

Comment: The ``NF-1`` thing ..  .. counting backwards was easier for me :)

Comment: Thanks, That's working on a fixed number of fields, what if the "value" on succeeding lines are no longer in "$4,$7" say it positioned to "$3 and $6" then "$2 and $9"

Comment: @paulsinohin then you should use a semantic ``regex`` approach

Comment: To get any number of values after ``name`` see my edited answer @paulsinohin

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.*("name":")([^"]*)".*\1([^"]*)".*/\2 \3/p;d' file
```

This extracts the fields following the two `name` keys and prints them if successful.

Alternatively, on simply pattern matching:

```
sed -r 's/.*:.*:"([^"]*)".*:"([^"]*)".*:.*/\1 \2/p;d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you could do

```
awk -F ":|," '{print $4,$7}' file2 |tr -d '"'
```

and get

```
AA AAxxxxxx
BB BBxxxxxx
AA CCxxxxxx
BB DDxxxxxx
```

Here, the field separator is either `:` or `,`, we print the fourth and seventh field (because all lines have the entries in these two fields) and finally, we use `tr` to delete the `"` because you don't want to have it.

Comment: Thanks, That's working on a fixed number of fields, what if the "value" on succeeding lines are no longer in "$4,$7" say it positioned to "$3 and $6" then "$2 and $9"?